# php-fpm-5.6.2 and mod_vhost_alias ProxyPassMatch

Tags: php-fpm, apache-2.2

I've been using successfully fcgi for php and mod_vhost_alias. Now with new server I was looking into php-fpm which looks interesting with Apache/2.4.6 on CentOS 7. php-fpm setup is working fine but together with mod_vhost_alias I"m not able to construct proper ProxyPassMatch rule.

My `mod_vhost_alias` setup is `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%-2.0.%-1.0/%-3+/`

Any ideas how to create proper match for any .php to pass to php-fpm running on fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000.

No matter what I do I get only AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'

Answer (score 1):

Try with `FilesMatch \.php$` instead of `ProxyPassMatch`.

Eg.

```
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
  </FilesMatch>
```

See a full example: [Dynamic development area with Apache 2.4 and PHP-FPM](http://float64.uk/blog/2014/08/22/dynamic-development-area-apache-php-fpm/)

I hope this help.

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall on this for over a week. Note that this method requires Apache 2.4.10 or above, so it isn't useful for default Apache 2.4.6 that comes in the CentOS 7 base repositories.